# NSUserDefaults setValue: deletes my plist. What's happening?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

Somehow, the below mentioned code seems to delete my `~/Library/Preferences/NAME.PRODUCT.plist`

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:NO forKey:@"ViewFirstShown"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

I can confirm the plist file exists before these lines are called. But the plist file disappears immediately after running the above codes.

I thought `synchronise` writes the values to the `disk` immediately. I tried waiting a while too, but the plist just doesn't re-appear.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't quite enough information to really answer your question here.

Is the "ViewFirstShown" key the only key in the preferences plist at the time the code above is executed? If so, then the `-setValue:forKey:` call is removing the last key in the prefs, which will remove the preferences plist.

One other thing to note is that you're using `-[NSUserDefaults setValue:forKey:]` which takes an `id` for the value. Because `NO` is `0L` and that's effectively `nil` you're removing any value that's here. You probably want to be using `-[NSUserDefaults setBool:forKey:]` instead.

Comment: Thanks! That's really what happened. `ViewFirstShown` is the only key in the plist. and i changed it to `setBool` and everything worked!